# How is a debugger like GDB able to run a program one instruction at a time?

Tags: windows, debugging, gdb

I can understand how a program that is compiled specifically for debugging can have breakpoints and traps inserted in the code, but how are programs like GDB able to do this on pre-compiled programs? How are they able to halt the execution of a program after every single instruction?

I am working on a Windows machine, but I'd be willing to learn how this works on Linux too.

Any direction or resources would be appreciated, since Googling returns instructions on how to use GDB, not how it works at a low level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How are they able to halt the execution of a program after every single instruction?

Most processors, including all `i*86` ones, support single-step execution.

When GDB is asked to execute a single machine instruction on such a processor, it's a very simple procedure:

1. arrange for the processor to execute in single-step mode (this is processor specific, read about `i*86` implementation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_flag)).
2. resume the inferior process
3. wait for interruption (which will come immediately after 1 instruction has finished if step 1 worked).

On a processor without single-step support, GDB's job is a bit more complicated:

1. disassemble current instruction (to know where the next one begins; this is trivial on RISC processors with fixed instruction size),
2. insert a temporary breakpoint on the next instruction (this is a bit complicated due to control transfer instructions -- the next instruction may be far away)
3. resume the inferior process
4. wait for interruption (which will come immediately after 1 instruction has finished if step 2 worked).
5. remove the temporary breakpoint inserted in step 2.

Resources:

- you can read the [source of GDB](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git), though it's not the easiest code to navigate.
- there was a series of [blog posts](http://system.joekain.com/debugger/) by Joseph Kain explaining how things work, though it appears to have stalled.